# can anyone help me to understand this c++ code?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I explain you the working of this program.

step 1: enter the no. of time you want to run the loop.

step 2: enter two strings s1 and s2.

output : it will give you a string s3 that does not contain any character from string s2.

problem: I am unable to understand the working of for loop, and why the value of hash is 257, and how is loops working.

The code is given below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    cout<<"enter any no. to run the loop"<<endl;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s1,s2,s3;
        int i,j,l1,l2;
    cout<<"enter two strings s1 and s2"<<endl;
        cin>>s1>>s2;
        l1=s1.length( );
         l2=s2.length( );
         int hash[257];
         for(i=0;i<257;i++)
         {
             hash[i]=0;
         }
          for(i=0;i<l2;i++)
         {
             hash[s2[i]]++;
         }
         
          for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
         {
             if(hash[s1[i]]==0)
             s3=s3+s1[i];
         }
         cout<<s3<<endl;
         
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are three `for` loops in your code, which one do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: As for the value `257`, it seems that the code assumes that `char` is `unsigned` (it's really implementation defined) and that the systems standard alphabet have 256 letters (which makes the choice of `257` a little odd since the characters will be numbered `0` to `255`).

Comment: And where did you get this code from? Didn't the origin contain any explanation about the code? And take this as a lesson to *always* document your code, and add comments about what it does and why it does what it does, what algorithms are used, etc.

Comment: sir i want to understand all three loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program figures out which characters in the first string are not contained in the second string.

Example input for the program:

```
1
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
helloworld
```

Example output (thanks to @mch for correction)

```
abcfgijkmnpqstuvxyz
```

Edit: Note that this is of course case sensitive as characters `a` and `A` produce different integer values.

Here is some commentary on the program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    // Do the whole program as many times as the user says
    int t;
    cout << "enter any no. to run the loop" << endl;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        string s1, s2, s3;
        int i, j, l1, l2;
        // read strings and get their respective lengths
        cout << "enter two strings s1 and s2" << endl;
        cin >> s1 >> s2;
        l1 = s1.length();
        l2 = s2.length();

        // Array with 257 elements
        int hash[257];
        // Initialize all elements of array with 0
        for (i = 0; i < 257; i++) {
            hash[i] = 0;
        }

        // Count occurrences of characters in second string
        // s2[i] is the character at position i in s2
        // Increase the value of hash for this character by 1
        for (i = 0; i < l2; i++) {
            hash[s2[i]]++;
        }

        // Iterate over s1 characters
        // If hash[i] == 0: character i is not contained in s2
        // s3 => string of letters in s1 that are not contained in s2
        for (i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
            if (hash[s1[i]] == 0)
                s3 = s3 + s1[i];
        }

        // output s3
        cout << s3 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side note: `cin>>s2` reads a word, not a line, so `s2` is `hello`, not `hello World`. This can be confirmed by looking at the output, it has `r` and `d` in it.

Comment: @mch, thanks for the hint, i didn't double check my output.

Answer (score 0):

The code computes an histogram of occurrences of the letters in `s1` and copies the letters of `s2` that have zero occurrence.

It can crash for any `char` type not restricted to the range `[0,256]` (!)

Answer (score 0):

There's a comment above explaining the for-loops.

`int hash[257]` could actually be `int hash[256]` . There are 256 different values that can fit in a `char` (8 bits).